# Why can't I convert this to the "Pointer Type"? So it can be used on all 3 types "mouse click, pen, touch. Help would be much appreciated

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, touch-event

Why can't I convert this to the "Pointer Type"? So it can be used on all 3 types "mouse click, pen, touch. Help would be much appreciated. It works as it is right now, but only with mouse click. I've tried several gestures, debugging on chrome.  I'm outta ideas on this one.

```
const item = document.querySelector(".item")

let isResizing = false;

window.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);

function mousedown(e) {
  let prevX = e.clientX;
  let prevY = e.clientY;

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);

  function mousemove(e) {
    if (!isResizing) {
      let newX = prevX - e.clientX;
      let newY = prevY - e.clientY;

      const rect = item.getBoundingClientRect();

      item.style.left = rect.left - newX + "px";
      item.style.top = rect.top - newY + "px";

      prevX = e.clientX;
      prevY = e.clientY;
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);

  function mouseup() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);

  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert this to the pointer type"?

Comment: pointer type = "Touch event, Pen/stylist and mouse click", not just mouse click.